# .htaccess complex rewrite rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a little complex rewrite rule and I can't get the hang of it.

What I want to do is use .htaccess to make my website see this link:

```
https://some-domain.com/human/jeff
```

As this link (because the system knows how to handle this link):

```
https://some-domain.com/?type=human&which=jeff
```

**Notes:**

1. I want to apply this rule only if `type=human`.
2. `which` param can contain only letter characters.
3. If the type is human, there wont be any more url params except for those.

After a lot of trying this is my final and failed .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule     ^(https://[^/]+)/?\?type=(human)&which=([a-zA-z]+)$ $1/$2/$3 [NC, L]
```

Here is the logic behind it:

- Group 1: `(https://[^/]+)` $1 will contain any string matching `https://{any non empty string that does not containing "/"}` - https://some-domain.com
- Static: `/?\?` matches "/?" or "?"
- Group 2: `type=(human)` $2 will contain "human"
- Group 3: `which=([a-zA-z]+)` $3 will contain a non empty string with only letter characters (jeff).

Expected result:
This will match the regex

```
https://{any non empty string that does not containing "/"}/human/{any non empty string}
```

And I'm pretty much stuck here

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I Should also mention that the rewrite should be for POST requests only, and the post params are needed.

Comment: You are using invalid characters in your Rewrite pattern. `http` , `domain` and `querystring` are there different things that can not be matched in `RewriteRule` . You need to use `RewriteCond` directive.. Not sure how the answer bellow worked for you.

Comment: @starkeen Actually I was wrong, it didn't work. can you help me with the rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Michał Turczyn and Mohammed Elhag for helping.
Here is the final and working content of .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(human)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(human)/(.*)$ /?type=$1&which=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This rule applies only when the REQUEST_URI is /human/{any non empty string}

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern: `^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)\?type=(human)&which=([a-z]+)$`

`^` - beginning of a string

`https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/` - match `http` literally, then match `s` optionally (zero or one), `\/\/` matches `//` literally, `[^\/]+` matches on or more characters otehr than `/` and then matches `/` literally

`\?type=(human)&which=([a-z]+)` - match `?` literally, then match `type=human` literally (`human` will be stored in captruing group), then match `&which=` literally, then match one or more letters with `[a-z]`

It will match your string when it is in desird form (`type=human` and only letters in `which`).

Substitution pattern: `\1\2\/\3`

`\1` - replace with first capturing group, similairly for `\2` and `\3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4BjGe/2)

Comment: is this what you mean? `RewriteRule        ^(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)\?type=(human)&which=([a-z]+)$           \1\2\/\3`

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan Yes, but I think you'd need to use `$1` instead of `\1`. Try it out :)

Answer (score 1):

In this line :

```
RewriteRule     ^(https://[^/]+)/?\?type=(human)&which=([a-zA-z]+)$ $1/$2/$3 [NC, L]
```

This part `^(https://[^/]+)/?\?type=(human)&which=([a-zA-z]+)$` is pattren and should match against a `URI` but not full `URL`.

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=(human)&which=([A-Za-z]+)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(human)/(.*)$ /?type=$1&which=$2 [L]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.

Comment: TY Mohammed, could you explain this line? `RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]`

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan this is RewriteRule so , the pattern (Regex) ^ to match any thing and then in substitution (target) %1 represent fist captured group in previous condition (human) and %2 represent the second captured  group ([A-Za-z])